# How to get Image Uri which is displayed on full screen?

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

Okay so I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution for my problem.

I am trying to develop an android application which will have some background running service. Suppose I opened Gallery and I am seeing some photo and I want my service to store that image's Uri. The problem is how to get image Uri which is being displayed on the screen. Also I want to extend it to Gallery Grid View where I can select multiple photos and ask my service to store their Uris.

I tried using reflection to get object of ViewImage.java class and invoke getCurrentUri() method. But I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

I am looking for a solution even if it requires my app to be system app, rooted device or using reflection to access android gallery code.

I want to get the Uris for Currently played videos or currently selected videos and music files along with documents like pdf, word.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is how to get image Uri which is being displayed on the screen.

Fortunately, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. The interaction between the image-viewing app and the user is between the app and the user; others cannot spy on that information, barring security flaws in the app.

> I want to get the Uris for Currently played videos or currently selected videos and music files along with documents like pdf, word.

Fortunately, that too is not possible, barring security flaws.

> I tried using reflection to get object of ViewImage.java class and invoke getCurrentUri() method. But I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

Other apps are running in other processes; you cannot use reflection to access them.

> I am looking for a solution even if it requires my app to be system app, rooted device or using reflection to access android gallery code.

A custom ROM could probably spy on the communications enough to achieve your ends.